# Calculate minimum of function using KKT theorem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

So I have this exercise I found in old exams.

Using KKT conditions solve the optimization problem ($, P, min) where

f(x,y) = x^2 + (y-4)^2, and

$ = {(x,y) from R^2; x + 3y <= 10 and x -2y <= 1 and x^2-4x+y <= 0}

---

I used 3 KKT conditions and got this equations:

Lx = 2x + &1 + &2 + 2&3 * x -4&3 = 0;

Ly = 2y - 8 + 3&1 + 2&2 + &3 = 0;

&1(x+3y-10) = 0;

&2(x-2y-1) = 0;

&3(x^2-4x+y) = 0;

where &i is lambda with index i;

So now what? Do I have to check for every constraint whether it is active or not? But that is 8 options... is there another way?

Comment: do not use $ and & in your question, it is hard to understand where you have made syntactical mistake or it is part of your problem. Apart from that they are reserved keyword for mathjax, it inferres in formatting.